# Smooth animation of SlideToggle containing an <li> element with a relative width

Tags: jquery, html, css

In the code blow I created a mobile menu consisting of an `<image>` and a `<navigation>`.

The `<navigation>` is displayed based on a **SlideToggle** function of jQuery.
The problem is that when you push the `<container>` the menu does not come out **smoothly**. The `1.0 Main Menu` slides in **nicely** whereas the other two are **skipped in**. It does look like there is an **interruption** in the animation.

As main reason I identified the property `height: 100%;` which I put under `.navigation > ul > li`. Once I delete this property the animation does work perfectly.

However, I want to achieve that the height of the `<li>` has a dependency on the height of the `<ul>` which again depends on the height of the `<navigation>` depending on the height of the `<header>`. Therefore, when I adjust the height of the **header** all child-elements are adjusted accordingly.

What do I have to change in my code to have a **relative height** for the `<li>` element and a **smooth animation** of the **SlideToggle** without interruption?

You can also find my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p6dqLLj6/28/).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".container").on('click', function () {
        $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle(500);
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.image {
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}

.navigation {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: fuchsia;
}

.bars {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 4% 0;
}

.navigation > ul {
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;
  right:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: blue;
}

 .navigation > ul > li {
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: Cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"> 

 <div class="image">
 Image
  </div>
  
  <nav class="navigation"> 
  
    <div class="container">
      <div class="bars">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    
       <ul class="panel">
          <li> 1.0 Main Menu </li>
          <li> 2.0 Main Menu </li>
          <li> 3.0 Main Menu </li>
       </ul>

  </nav>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved the animation from jQuery to CSS which makes it smoother. jQuery is not know for its speed of animating. Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").on('click', function() {
    $(".panel").toggleClass('opened');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.image {
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}

.navigation {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: fuchsia;
}

.bars {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 4% 0;
}

.navigation>ul {
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
   transform: translate(0, -300%);
   transition: transform .3s ease;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: blue;
}

  .navigation>ul.opened {
   transform: translate(0, 100%);
  }


.navigation>ul>li {
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: Cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">

  <div class="image">
    Image
  </div>

  <nav class="navigation">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="bars">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <ul class="panel">
      <li> 1.0 Main Menu </li>
      <li> 2.0 Main Menu </li>
      <li> 3.0 Main Menu </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi Gerard, thanks for your answer but how can I make it slide in below the header and not from above the page?

Comment: @Michi you would have to restructure your HTML and work with z-index

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".container").on('click', function () {
        $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle(500);
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.image {
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}

.navigation {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: fuchsia;
}

.bars {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 4% 0;
}

.navigation > ul {
  height: 200px;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;
  right:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: blue;
}

 .navigation > ul > li {
  height: 33.33%;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: Cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"> 

 <div class="image">
 Image
  </div>
  
  <nav class="navigation"> 
  
    <div class="container">
      <div class="bars">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    
       <ul class="panel">
          <li> 1.0 Main Menu </li>
          <li> 2.0 Main Menu </li>
          <li> 3.0 Main Menu </li>
       </ul>

  </nav>
  
</div>
```

I applied specific height for navigation > ul and applied height to the following `li`(navigation > ul > li) in percentage.